# Xamarin android target platform not selectable with cross platform?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

[image show only ios target platform is selectable but android target platform cant be select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y44Lu.jpg)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question. It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You do not have the necessary Android components installed.

Comment: thanx, it solved ,(issue with android component, it not installed) i install itmanually and it works

Comment: @KrishnaGhatul How did you install manually ?

Comment: @KrishnaGhatul Nevermind. I just re-run the installer and it installed andoird & .net components again. Now it's working.